# Cannot send email in perl

Tags: perl, email, cgi, sendmail

For some reason I cannot send an email in perl. I checked my env path and sendmail path everything is correct. But I am not receiving the email.I am not entirely sure if I am missing something.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;

print header;
print start_html("Results");



$ENV{PATH} = "/usr/sbin" ;

open (MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t") or 
    &dienice("Can't fork for sendmail: $!\n");

my $recipient = "myusername\@gmail.com";

print MAIL "To: $recipient\n";

print MAIL "From: nobody\@cgi101.com\n" ;

print MAIL "Subject: Form Data\n\n";

foreach my $p (param()) {
    print MAIL "$p = ", param($p), "\n";
}

close(MAIL);

print <<EndHTML;
<h2>Thank You</h2>
<p>Thank you for writing!</p>
<p>Return to our <a href="index.html">home page</a>.</p>
EndHTML

print end_html;
```

Comment: What's in your error log?

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely hard to tell what the issue might be.  I'm assuming mail works normally from the command prompt?

That said, have you tried MIME::Lite?

```
use MIME::Lite;

my $body = <<EndHTML;
<h2>Thank You</h2>
<p>Thank you for writing!</p>
<p>Return to our <a href="index.html">home page</a>.</p>
EndHTML

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
  Type    => 'text/html',
  From    => 'nobody@cgi101.com',
  To      => 'myusername@gmail.com',
  Subject => 'Form Data',
  Data    => $body
);

$msg->send;
```

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to give much help without knowing what errors you are getting. But it's 2014 and we can probably do a little better than talking directly to sendmail to send an email.

For email handling, you should probably be looking in the Email::* namespace on CPAN. In particular, [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email%3a%3aSender) is the recommended approach for sending email.